# My SQL sum returning double values

Tags: php, mysql

The following query

```
SELECT 
invoices.id,
SUM(payments.amount)
FROM adass.invoices 
INNER JOIN adass.payments ON invoices.id=payments.id_invoice 
GROUP BY invoices.id ORDER BY 1 desc LIMIT 0, 25
```

returns the following result

[image]

However, when I join another table to the query like so:

```
SELECT 
invoices.id,
SUM(payments.amount)
FROM adass.invoices 
INNER JOIN adass.invoice_items ON invoices.id=invoice_items.id_invoice 
INNER JOIN adass.payments ON invoices.id=payments.id_invoice 
GROUP BY invoices.id ORDER BY 1 desc LIMIT 0, 25
```

It duplicates the payment amount for invoice id 13919, effectively doubling the payment of 100 in the table

[image]

What is causing this?

I've added the table contents below

INVOICE ITEMS TABLE
[image]

PAYMENTS TABLE
[image]

> UPDATE: Larger query as follows

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS invoices.id,
COALESCE(SUM(invoice_items.gross),0) AS gross,
COALESCE(SUM(invoice_items.net) - SUM(invoice_items.gross),0) AS vat,
COALESCE(SUM(invoice_items.net),0) AS net,
COALESCE(SUM(payments.amount),0),
COALESCE(SUM(payments.amount) - SUM(invoice_items.net),0) AS outstanding
FROM adass.invoices 
LEFT JOIN adass.invoice_items ON invoices.id=invoice_items.id_invoice 
LEFT JOIN adass.payments ON invoices.id=payments.id_invoice 
GROUP BY invoices.id ORDER BY 1 desc LIMIT 0, 25
```

> RESULT:
>   [image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's clear what's going on. Your INVOICE #13919 has two INVOICE ITEMS, hence you get **double** the amount of invoice payment because your query is generating two rows. If you had three INVOICE ITEMS, then the amount would have been tripled.

You need to remove this clause from your query `INNER JOIN adass.invoice_items ON invoices.id=invoice_items.id_invoice` since you are not using columns from `adass.invoice_items` anyway.

Your query then will be:

```
SELECT invoices.id,
       SUM(payments.amount)
  FROM adass.invoices 
 INNER JOIN adass.payments ON invoices.id=payments.id_invoice 
GROUP BY invoices.id ORDER BY 1 desc LIMIT 0, 25
```

Comment: It is a simplified query for demonstration purposes. I've added in more of what the query returns